# ES6 dynamic destructuring

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I need to apply different destructuring for the function response depending of global flag [single service for multiple apps]

```
// Destructuring template should be defined as value
let destructuringTemplate;
if (flag) {
   destructuringTemplate = {data: {classA: user}};
} else {
   destructuringTemplate = {data: {classB: user}};
}
// This technique would not work, this is just my idea representation.
this.getUser(({destructuringTemplate: user) => { this.localUser = user });
```

At this moment it works this way:

```
let destructuringTemplate;
if (flag) {
   destructuringTemplate = ({data: {classA: user}}) => user;
} else {
   destructuringTemplate = ({data: {classB: user}}) => user;
}
this.getUser(response => { this.localUser = destructuringTemplate(response)};
```

it is kinda ugly, some suggestion how it should be done?

Comment: do you want to pick user, depending on the flag?

Comment: the idea is extract certain property of an object, returned by some function

Answer (score 5):

You could use a [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) with a [conditional (ternary) operator `?:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

```js
var flag = true,
    object = { data: { classA: 'foo', classB: 'bar' } },
    { data: { [flag ? 'classA' : 'classB']: user } } = object,
    { data: { [!flag ? 'classA' : 'classB']: user1 } } = object;

console.log(user);
console.log(user1);
```

Comment: I want to use the flag only once because multiple declarations are based on it. this is much more simplified version of my code, the main idea is increase simplicity

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use destructuring, use simple dot/bracket notation:

```
const userClass = flag ? 'classA' : 'classB'
this.getUser(response => { this.localUser = response.data[userClass] })
```

If you want to reuse this logic, just create simple function, e.g.:

```
const extractUser = response => response.data[userClass]
```

Comment: data has multiple layers, depending of "flag" state, user object can be on a different level

Comment: @BohdanShcherbak sure, create a helper function and reuse the logic

Comment: That is my current solution, but i want to improve it